# Microsoft Access Report Events vba

Tags: ms-access, vba

Microsoft Access Report.open Event.  I have the following code running when I open a pdf report

```
Private Sub Report_open(Cancel As Integer)

Me.Filter = "Account_id in(102) And [Level 3] ='Other')"

Me.FilterOn = True

End Sub
```

I changed this code to

```
Private Sub Report_open(Cancel As Integer)

Me.Filter = "Account_id in(102) And [Level 3] in('Equityarb','Other')"

Me.FilterOn = True

End Sub
```

and tested it and it worked   and saved and got out of report  Upon opening the report  the CHANGES were not in effect  .  Cant get the change to save

Answer (score 0):

Compact and repair.  Do it again.  That usually fixes weird stuff like that.